# Rust Toolchain location - Fedora 35

Tags: intellij-idea, rust, fedora

I'm using Fedora 35, and no matter what location I've tried for the Rust Toolchain in IntelliJ IDEA I get "Invalid toolchain location: can't find Cargo in..." I've tried /bin and many, many other locations.
I prefer not to use rustup and would like to do this with the standard Fedora Rust installation.

Comment: Good luck. I've had this _temporarily_ working on NixOS, but -- as documented in https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/8320 -- have never been able to get it to "stick" without giving up and switching to rustup. I sincerely hope you get an answer (or simply troubleshooting/debugging hints) here that are applicable to that situation as well.

Comment: Just wondering ... `rustup` seems to work great.  Is there a reason not to use it?

Comment: Assuming you have cargo working in a terminal, what is the output of `which cargo`?

Comment: @rickhg12hs when I went to install rustup it said I should remove any other installations of rust, and I prefer to have the standard version of Rust that is installed through Fedora dnf to make it easily integrated and upgraded with the rest of the system.

Comment: @hkBst 'which cargo' prints '/usr/bin/cargo'. I've tried that but still get "Invalid toolchain location".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it has to do with the sandbox effect of Flatpaks. I reinstalled IDEA from Fedora's Copr instead of the Flatpak and everything was read automatically.

Comment: While suffering the same problem. I tried it from the intellij terminal: I did a `cargo build` it worked flawlessly. Therefore it does not appear to be a containerisation problem (probably). However I have not been able to find a solution.

Comment: I just downloaded from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=linux and have exactly the same problem.

Comment: I have added a bug report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-303383/Rust-plugin-not-working-It-says-that-it-can-not-find-cargo-However-cargo-is-present-and-accessible

Answer (score 1):

I had to install

`sudo dnf install rust-src`

Then set the path in IntelliJ to:

`/usr/lib/rustlib/src/rust`